# jqgrid viewGridRow bug?

Tags: jqgrid

I'm using the tableToGrid feature, along with the viewGridRow feature.  When the viewGridRow method is called, the dialog displays correctly.  But when paging through records using the Pager Buttons, OR when you close the dialog and execute the viewGridRow method on another record, the values for all columns whose names have a space (" ") in them do not get updated.  They keep the value that was placed there by the first viewGridRow execution.  The values for all columns whose names do NOT have a space get updated as they should.

I've tried recreateForm:true (although this is a property of the editGridRow method, and not the viewGridRow method), and this did not resolve the issue.  Also tried various, semi-random combinations of other settings.

Below is my code.  Ideas?

```
tableToGrid("#mytable", height:'400',
 ondblClickRow: function(rowid,iRow,iCol,e) {
 jQuery("#mytable").viewGridRow(rowid, {closeOnEscape:true});
 }
});
<table id="mytable">
<thead>
 <tr class="header">
 <th id="CustomerID">CustomerID</th>
 <th id="Account ID">Account ID</th>
 <th id="Customer">Customer</th>
 <th id="System">System</th>
 <th id="Make/Model">Make/Model</th>
 <th id="Modality">Modality</th>
 <th id="Last Login">Last Login</th>
 <th id="Attachments">Attachments</th>
 <th id="Alerts">Alerts</th>
 <th id="Last Log Entry">Last Log Entry</th>
 <th id="Last HE Level">Last HE Level</th>
 <th id="HE Level Threshold">HE Level Threshold</th>
 <th id="DBOD Threshold">DBOD Threshold</th>
 <th id="HE Data Latency">HE Data Latency</th>
 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 <tr>
 <td>1</td>
 <td>32222222</td>
 <td>ABC Company</td>
 <td>Smith Warehouse Bay #1</td>
 <td>Make/Model</td>
 <td>MRI</td>
 <td>Dec 20 2010 12:18PM by Frank Smith</td>
 <td>0</td>
 <td>0</td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td>60</td>
 <td>0.35</td>
 <td></td>
 </tr>
 …
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is that you explicitly define ids for the `<th>` elements of the `<table>` which you convert to the jqGrid. How you can see from the source code of `tableToGrid` function (the most interesting are [the lines 37-38](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/js/grid.tbltogrid.js#L37), the `name` and the `index` column properties will be get from the `<th>` elements if there exist. The ids having blanks are mot supported by jqGrid because they don't work in many of the jQuery selectors.

Please read also [the reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier) which describes restrictions in CSS identifiers. You should follow the restrictions.

So I recommend you just remove the id attributes from the `<th>` elements or choose another values without blanks for the ids.

Comment: Thank you, Oleg.  But I had to define the ids in the <th> elements because I'm also using setColProp and other methods for which I need to identify specific columns.  When I remove the ids in the <th> elements, these methods fail.  Is there another way to identify specific columns, other than assigning ids to the <th> elements?

Comment: Oh, wait.  I see.  You can still reference the column by name (<th>RecordID</th>, but it still can't have spaces in the name. Is there no way to escape the spaces (tried a leading backslash \ but this didn't work)...?

Comment: @user569095: In the lines 37-38 of the code (see my answer) you will see, that `tableToGrid` build names with respect of replacing of spaces to '_'. For example "Account_ID" instead of "Account ID". You can access the column with the name.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry, I see it now.  The answer is this:  <th id="Record_ID">Record ID</th>

Comment: @user569095: Yes, but if you will use `<th>Record ID</th>` you receive **absolutely the same results** as with `<th id="Record_ID">Record ID</th>`.